# Probability That Randomly Selected Two Square -Chords Intersects

Tags: probability, geometry

There is a similar question about circle, which can easily be seen probability is ${1 \over 3}$ for chords to intersect.My question is

> Assume a square ABCD , two points P and Q are randomly selected on two different sides. Again other two points R and S selected in same way. What is the probability that PQ and RS intersects ($P_i)$.

Note: P & R or Q & R can be on same side. In other words among P,Q,R,S at most two points can be on same side.
For this question let call PQ & RS square chords.

My Attempt:

Attempt 1**

I try to solve this question by symmetry just like we did it in circles . Let took a case easy to observe. PQ is diagonal AD. Now i can select other two points on AB-BC , AB-AD , AB_CD , BC-AD , BC-CD & AD-CD. From these 6 cases, in four cases PQ and RS intersects . So Probability $P_i={4 \over 6}={2 \over 3}$.

Now i am not sure this answer is correct.

Attempt 2**

Let grab our square and place it on a circle. If we extend our square chords they are also chords of circles. But i failed to Separate  this case from circle. Using symmetry i got intuition that answer should be ${1 \over 3}$.

Attempt 3**

Now lift our square and place it on Cartesian Coordinates. Assume A is at origin. Let $P(x,0)$ and $Q(0,y)$. Now for intersection required probability is
$$P=\frac{x+y}{4a}.\frac{4a-(x+y)}{4a}$$
Let $x+y=t$ , now t varies from 0 to 2a. Taking average
$$P_i={1 \over {16a^2}}\int_{0}^{2a}t.(4a-t)dt=\frac{2a(2a)^2-{(2a)^3 \over 3}}{16a^2}={1 \over 3}$$

Which one is correct.

Only if answer is different then circle :

> Can we generalize it for a n side polygon. We should get $\lim_{n \to \infty}P_i={1 \over 3}$

Comment: Through numerical simulations, it seems to be somewhere around $0.47$, not $1/3$.

Comment: Then what is wrong and how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can assume that $P = (0, y_p)$ is on the left side of a unit square with the bottom left corner at $(0, 0)$. Let us now consider cases:

If $Q = (x_q, 1)$ is on the top side, then either $R$ or $S$, but not both, have to be in the section of the square cut off by $PQ$. The probability of this happening is $2 \left(\frac{1-y_p}{4} \cdot \frac{3-x_q}{3}+\frac{x_q}{4}*\frac{2+y_p}{3} \right) = \frac{(1-y_p)(3-x_q)+x_q(2+y_p)}{6}$.

Integrating that from $x_q = 0...1$ and $y_p = 0...1$, we get that the probability of the two chords intersecting is $\frac{5}{12}$ if $Q$ is on the top.

Since it is just a reflection over an axis if $Q$ is on the bottom side, I will skip that. We end up getting the same answer of $\frac 5 {12}$ if $Q$ is on the bottom.

The harder one is if $P$ and $Q$ are on opposite sides. Let $Q = (1, y_q)$. For $PQ$ and $RS$ to intersect, $R$ and $S$ have to be on opposite sides of $PQ$. The probability of this happening is $2 \left( \frac 1 4 \cdot \frac{1+y_p+y_q} 3 + \frac{1-y_p} 4 \cdot \frac{1+y_q} 3 + \frac{1-y_q} 4 \cdot \frac{1+y_p} 3 \right) = \frac{3+y_p+y_q-2y_p y_q}{6}$.

Integrating that from $y_p = 0...1$ and $y_q = 0...1$, we get that the probability of the two chords intersecting is $\frac{7}{12}$ if $Q$ is on the right.

Finally, we have that the requested probability is $\frac{\frac{5}{12}+\frac{5}{12}+\frac{7}{12}}{3} = \frac{17}{36} \approx 0.47$ which matched up with numerical simulations.

Comment: Then which case i missed , also is there a way to generalize it.

Comment: And one more what are Numerical simulations, Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @Rishi. Numerical simulation: Give the computer a square, e.g with vertices $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0).$ Using a random-number generator, choose a set $\{P,Q,R,S\}$ that meets the conditions of the problem. (i.e. $P,Q$ on the sides but not on the same side & $R,S$ etc. ...). The computer will then compute whether $PQ$ meets $RS.$ This is one sample. Do a very large number of samples and count how often $PQ$ meets $RS$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  Is there a software which we use for it

Comment: @Rishi I just used Python.